# jQuery - getting val() of parents grandchildren

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

http://jsfiddle.net/7uygxcdL/7/

I'm trying to get the val of a grandchild of the parent div on a select change.
I'll included a fiddle, but can put code here as needed...

So in the example.. if you change the first select, I want to console log key 1 and val 1

If you change the seconds, I want key 2 and val 2...

I'm going to read up on the DOM of jquery lookups now..

```
$('.reward_select').change(function(){
    console.log($(this).next('input[name="reward_key"]').val());
    console.log($(this).next('input[name="reward_value"]').val());
});
```

And my HTML:

```
    <div class="reward_entry">
        <div class="reward_item">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <select name="item_type[]" class="reward_select">
                    <option value="1">option 1</option>
                    <option value="2">option 2</option>
                    <option value="3">option 3</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="reward_key[]" value="key 1" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2-offset-5">
                <input type="text" name="reward_value[]" value="val 1" />
            </div>
      </div>
    ====================
      <div class="reward_item">
          <div class="col-sm-2">
              <select name="item_type[]" class="reward_select">
                  <option value="1">option 1</option>
                  <option value="2">option 2</option>
                  <option value="3">option 3</option>
              </select>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input type="text" name="reward_key[]" value="key 2" />
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-2-offset-5">
              <input type="text" name="reward_value[]" value="val 2" />
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/7uygxcdL/9/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7uygxcdL/12/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selector is not correct. `select` element does not have immediately following sibling `input`. You can change your code to:

```js
$('.reward_select').change(function() {
  console.log($(this).parent().next().children().val());
  console.log($(this).parent().next().next().children().val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reward_entry">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <select name="item_type[]" class="reward_select">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" name="reward_key[]" value="key 1" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2-offset-5">
    <input type="text" name="reward_value[]" value="val 1" />
  </div>====================
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <select name="item_type[]" class="reward_select">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" name="reward_key[]" value="key 2" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2-offset-5">
    <input type="text" name="reward_value[]" value="val 2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

If you can change your html mark-up I suggest to include `input` elements as child in element with class `col-sm-2`:

```js
$('.reward_select').change(function() {
  $(this).nextAll().children().each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reward_entry">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <select name="item_type[]" class="reward_select">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
    </select>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" name="reward_key[]" value="key 1" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2-offset-5">
      <input type="text" name="reward_value[]" value="val 1" />
    </div>
  </div>====================
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <select name="item_type[]" class="reward_select">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
    </select>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" name="reward_key[]" value="key 2" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2-offset-5">
      <input type="text" name="reward_value[]" value="val 2" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's cool...!! Is there a way to add a specific class look up too, just so my code kind of comments itself...

Comment: @Beertastic Check my alternative too if you are able to change html markup.

Comment: @Beertastic Update second example to get all `input` values using iteration.